# The error was: error while evaluating conditional

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

I try to use insert a unique number to each server I have by using Ansible.

As below, I wish these is:

"1" in 192.168.60.6's myid.txt

"2" in 192.168.60.7's myid.txt

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts:True
  vars:
    servers:
      host1:
        ip: 192.168.60.6
        num: 1
      host2:
        ip: 192.168.60.7
        num: 2
      host3:
        ip: 192.168.60.8
        num: 3

  tasks:
    -name: write a unique number in myid.txt 
     lineinfile:
       dest: "/home/user/myid.txt"
       line: "{{ item.value.num }}"
     when: "{{ item.value.ip }} == {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1] }}"
     `enter code here`with_dict: "{{ servers }}"
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
TASK [write unique number in myid] 

*********************************************
fatal: [192.168.60.6]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check '{{item.value.ip}} == {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1] }}' failed.   
The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{item.value.ip}} == {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1] }}): float object has no element 60

The error appears to have been in '/home/shihhao/Desktop/BlueTech/ansible/kafka_playbook.yml': line 101, column 7,   
but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
    - name: write unique number in myid
      ^ here\n"}
```

It seems once I add this line I will get the error.

```
 when: "{{item.value.ip}} == {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1] }}"
```

BTW: {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1] }} is 192.168.60.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use bare variables in your `when:` statement:

```
when: item.value.ip == ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1]
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement):

> This is easy to do in Ansible with the when clause, which contains a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces

Raw expressions are used in `when:` statement, with `assert` module and with `debug: var=varname` (**but** `debug: msg="{{varname}}"`).

Comment: Thanks Konstantin.

Comment: Thanks mate, but now I am so confused in which case should I use bare variables, and which another case should I  use variables in "{{ }}" , could you give me some advice?